# Is it improper for a woman to insist on being the only wife?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, women, husband-wife, polygamy

[Qur'an 4:3](https://quran.com/4/3) makes Islamically permissible men having more than one wife.  However, after some (comically unsuccessful) attempts at finding a husband, I can say the idea of my (inshallah) future husband having a second wife feels degrading to me.  My dream of finding a loving husband does not involve negotiations of a second wife.

I'm at a point where I feel I should insist on being the only wife.

**Question**: Is it improper for a woman to insist on being the only wife?

Obviously, a husband may choose to have just one wife, and (as far as know) this is the norm in Muslim society.  But I'm wondering if it's improper (as in haram, disliked, etc.) for a woman to obstruct her (current or future) husband from finding a second wife.

I'm not clear on this, maybe this is a perfectly acceptable decision that a woman may make.

Comment: in this question society also plays a important. but looking forward for a answer according to islam

Comment: @Uma The effect of this would be for the first wife to become entitled to a divorce in case he does, while he still would be able to legally marry a second wife, correct?

Comment: `this is the norm in Muslim society`....No it is not. The terms "Muslim culture" and "Muslim society" are misnomers. While Islam does provide a basis to the cultures of Muslims, their own cultures vary from nation to nation. Polygamy is more widely accepted in Arab world than it is in let's say Turkey, Central Asia and South Asia where polygamy exists and isn't unheard of but is viewed as peculiar and rare.

Comment: Personally (Not theologically) I'd say you are well-within your rights but then maybe it's my cultural blindspot. While I am a Muslim born to a family which has been Muslim for centuries, in a Muslim country, the social norms and laws here are different. People dislike polygamy and if a man insists on taking more than one wife, he has to deal with the law and his in-laws. The law is satisfied if the first wife grants the man permission to marry again (Without that permission he cannot marry another woman). If your husband is doing something you are not okay with, you can and should part ways

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER.** This is not meant to be a fatwa on the matter. Rather, it is a collection of the opinions expressed in multiple publications. One should always seek a fatwa from a scholar knowledgeable about the topics of marriage contracts and their consequences.

---

A woman may include a clause in the marriage contract to be the only wife according to a good number of scholars. In other words, this is considered appropriate, albeit that there is a difference of opinions on the consequences of such a condition.

Such a condition (according to the Hanbali school):

1. will not deprive the husband of his right to take additional wives,
2. will not render the husband's future marriages unlawful,
3. will allow the wife to exercise an annulment of the marriage contract at her own discretion which will be treated as any standard divorce (monetary compensation, custody, being able to remarry after *iddah*, etc.),
4. will allow the wife to forfeit her right to exercise an annulment of the marriage contract and continue with her marriage as one of the wives of her husband.

There is no defined time limit as to when she can exercise her rights if annulment of the marriage contract; this has to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis through a qualified *mufti*.

As per [Islam Q&A Fatwa 223559](https://islamqa.info/ar/223559) (Arabic only), we as Muslims are commanded to fulfill our contracts (long as said contracts do not make what is lawful unlawful, and vice versa — see [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Vol. 3, Book 13, Hadith 1352](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/15/32)):

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَوْفُوا بِالْعُقُودِ ۚ أُحِلَّتْ لَكُم بَهِيمَةُ الْأَنْعَامِ إِلَّا مَا يُتْلَىٰ عَلَيْكُمْ غَيْرَ مُحِلِّي الصَّيْدِ وَأَنتُمْ حُرُمٌ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَحْكُمُ مَا يُرِيدُ
>
> O you who have believed, fulfill [all] contracts. Lawful for you are the animals of grazing livestock except for that which is recited to you [in this Qur'an] - hunting not being permitted while you are in the state of ihram. Indeed, Allah ordains what He intends.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Ma'idah 5:1](https://quran.com/5/1)</sub>

Hence, a condition as such in a marriage contract must be respected or the wife gets the right to annul the marriage.

---

#### Hanafi

The Hanafi view is that a woman may not add such conditions to a marriage contract. However, if such were added to a marriage contract, they are not binding while the marriage contract itself remains valid otherwise (separability of clauses). [Muhammad al-Shaybani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Shaybani) said in [Al-Hujja, Vol. 3, pp. 214](https://ia800207.us.archive.org/6/items/waq16601/03_16603.pdf) that if such a condition is included in a marriage contract, it renders the contract valid, but the condition not binding.

---

#### Maliki

The Maliki view as explained by ['Illish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27Illish) in [Fath al-'Ali al-Malik, Vol. 1, pp. 335](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-21688#page-331) is that if such a condition is added to the marriage contract, there would be one of two courses:

1. The intention is to annul the marriage if the condition is not fulfilled, in which case, if the husband marries again, the previous wife is automatically divorced.
2. The intention is to give the wife the choice to annul or continue with the marriage.

---

#### Shafi'i

The Shafi'i school is the same as the Hanafi school. In [Rawdat at-Talibīn, Vol. 7, pp. 265](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1448&bk_no=95&flag=1), An-Nawawi said if a condition in a marriage contract contradicts the norms of marriage, said condition would not be binding, let that be that the husband does not take additional wives, not to divorce her, or have right-hand possessions, or not to have her travel with him, or to divorce any of his previous wives, etc.

---

#### Hanbali

The Hanbali view is explained by [Ibn Taymiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Taymiyyah) in [Majmū' al-Fatawa Vol. 32, pp. 170](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=5361&bk_no=22&flag=1) where he said that if the marriage contract stipulates that the husband should not take another wife, and he does, then the wife has the right to annul the marriage while keeping all her rights or to continue with the marriage. [Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_al-Jawziyya) shared the same view of his teacher in [I'lām al-Muwaqqi'īn, Vol. 1, pp. 238-239](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=101&bk_no=34&flag=1). He added that 'Umar ibn al-Khattab, Sa'd ibn Abi Waqqas, 'Amr ibn al-'Aas, and Mu'awiya ibn Abi Sufyan all agreed that a woman may put conditions in her marriage contract related to her lodging, place of residence, and not to have additional wives. [Ibn Qudamah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qudamah) also confirmed this in al-Mughni, Vol. 9, pp. 483.

Comment: @G.Bach  — Thank you for your feedback. I edited the answer accordingly.