# Can a wife deny her husband to marry more women?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, polygamy

Assalamu Alaikum brothers and sisters.
Does the wife in Islamic marriages have a say in whether the husband gets to marry more women?
In Islam, a man can marry up to 4 women, but can a wife reject that proposal?
I feel like some women wouldn't be comfortable with that and wouldn't wish to "share" their husband, and I've read that the only solution for women who don't want to be with a husband who wishes to marry more women is to divorce their husband according to their "marriage contract", but is it really just an either-or?
I'm a man myself, but I was just curious about this.
Of course, if it's not allowed, then I cannot disagree with the word of Allah.
Allah knows best. Thank you.

Edit: Again, for anyone reading my comment and thinking about disliking or are mad about it, I'm not against it if Allah has said it's impermissible. I will put my own feelings and opinions aside always if Allah has said how it is. I know Allah knows best and that my personal opinion has no say in Islamic rules. So I kindly ask anyone that's come across this question to not take it the wrong way. I'm simply curious.

Answer (score 2):

No, a wife can not deny her husband from marrying more than one woman.

The base law about multiple marriages is that it is permitted:

> #### فانكحوا ما طاب لكم من النساء مثنى وثلاث ورباع فإن خفتم ألا تعدلوا فواحدة
>
> Then marry those that please you of [other] women, two or three or four. But if you fear that you will not be just, then [marry only] one.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:3](https://quran.com/4/3?translations=20)</sup>

This is an absolute permission to perform polygyny, with the only condition being that the husband *himself* should feel that he is able to administer justice among his wives.

The verse does not lay any condition about seeking the permission or approval of a previous wife. And there is also no evidence found elsewhere that a wife's permission is needed:

> No evidence appears neither in the Qur’an nor sunnah requiring the permission of the first wife if her husband wishes to marry another wife, and therefore he is not required to ask her permission.
>
> <sup>— [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/61/)</sup>

As you have already noted, some madhabs allow the wife to place a condition at the time of the Nikah contract that the husband will not remarry and will otherwise divorce her. See [Is it improper for a woman to insist on being the only wife?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44909/)

It is not a legal requirement to seek the consent of the previous wife however doing so may be recommended as part of courtesy and good treatment.

> خياركم خياركم لنسائهم خلقا
>
> The best of you are those who are best to your women.
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/12/17)</sup>

Comment: "some madhabs allow the wife to place a condition at the time of the Nikah contract that the husband will not remarry and will otherwise divorce her" - such contracts are openly against the laws of Allah. +1

Comment: No, a contract is not against the law. Anyone can make a contract that about doing or not doing something that is permissible (haram). A contract is against the law if it impedes not to do something obligatory or to do something impermissible.

Answer (score -3):

Walaikum-Assalam. Yes she can deny that. As far I have known a married woman can deny her husband about marrying other woman.

Comment: No, religiously, she cannot. :( Legally, what she can do, depends on the law of the land.